# barwidth in histograms is not the same

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like [this](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZsOYWkZj1OcfzC4OqHW0QvYQNDITpCUEzYV).
If I plot a histogram of `pH.Value` for a specific `Uniprot.Recommended.Name` on a grid based on `Space.Group` with code like this

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = filter(massaged, Uniprot.Recommended.Name == "Myoglobin")) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = pH.Value)) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ Space.Group)
```

I get a plot like this [image].

Why do I have very thin bars (lines I would say) in the second `Space.Group` (P 21 21 21) and decent-width bars in the fourth `Space.Group` (P 43 21 2)? Is it possible to make all the bars have an equal width?

Thanks.

Ps. I did `head -n 1001 data > dummy.tsv` to my data. If you want the whole dataset just ask.

Comment: Have you tried geom_histogram()?

Comment: You are right @dario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data contain many NA's which I have omitted. By using `geom_histogram` the plot should look like you expect . I think.

```r
massaged <- read.delim("~/Downloads/dummy.tsv")
library(tidyverse)
df <- na.omit(massaged)
ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data = df, mapping = aes(x = pH.Value)) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ Space.Group)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

try controlling for bar width by adding a width argument. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = filter(massaged, Uniprot.Recommended.Name =="Myoglobin"), mapping = aes(x = pH.Value)) +
 geom_bar(width = 0.5) + 
facet_grid(. ~ Space.Group)
```